# How to propely use the multicols package in beamer?

Tags: beamer, multicol

Here is a small example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlipsumdefault{1-1}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tiny
\lipsum
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols*}{1}
\lipsum
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It works nicely, but I still get a warning:

```
Package multicol Warning: multicols* inside a box does not make sense.
(multicol)                Going to balance anyway on input line 13.
```

DO I so something wrong here? Is there a correct way for using the package with `beamer`? What other options does one have for having text flow from one column to another in `beamer`?

[image: This frame looks fine, doesn't it?]

To make this clearer, I provide another example, in which it seems very natural to use `multicols` rather than the manual division of text into columns:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}\columnseprule 0.4pt\raggedcolumns
\begin{document} \begin{frame}
  The main programming paradigms are:
\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Imperative
    \item Object Oriented
    \item Functional
    \item Logical
    \item Aspect Oriented
    \item Constraints
    \item Parallel
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols*}
However, there are many multi-paradigm programming languages.
\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Mathematica
    \item Oz
    \item F\#
    \item Visula Basic.Net
    \item C\#
    \item Scala
    \item Object Pascal
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols*}
\end{frame}\end{document}
```

And the output is[image]

Comment: You do know this is _far_ too much text, I assume? The entire design approach of the code in `beamer` is based around Till's idea of a good presentation.

Comment: Yes, I know... but `lipsum` cannot produce just little text. Sometimes however I have an itemized list, which I would like to present in two columns, without the need to balance the columns myself.

Comment: The problem is interesting; but you can't use `multicols*` in a beamer frame for the reason expressed in the warning: the contents is typeset in a box.

Comment: Yes, but it still works, doesn't it?

Comment: I edited the question, adding an example in which it is very natural to use multicols, even if with the requirement of using minimal text.

Comment: so what you want is to move all the items on the left column?

Answer (score 10):

The warning is from the `*` form `multicols*` and it is saying it's going to use `multicol` instead, so to avoid the warning use `multicols` not `multicols*`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlipsumdefault{1-1}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tiny
\lipsum
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}{1}
\lipsum
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the starred version of `multicols` is used

> all white space is automatically placed in the last column or columns. […]
>   [I]nstead of the usual environment the columns on the last page are not balanced.

The manual, which is the source of the quote above, does also explain the warning you are seeing:

> If we are not on the main galley, i.e., inside a box of some sort, that approach will not work since we don’t have a vertical size for the box so we better warn that we balance anyway.

Thus you need to remove the `*` or provide an environment that has some defined vertical size (apparently beamer frames are not detected as such, possibly related to the fact that its size is calculated rather late, cf. [Is there a simple command for the available height in a beamer slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278429)).

Additionally one should know in this context that the beamer package provides a *native* mechanism for multiple columns: the `columns` and `column` environments.