# Tikz-based beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I've created a beamer environment based on this discussion: [Is there a simple command for the available height in a beamer slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278429/is-there-a-simple-command-for-the-available-height-in-a-beamer-slide) The only issue is that it doesn't work with the overlays. Here is the MWE (to see the error, uncomment the line starting with `\only`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{tikzframe}[2][c]{%
\begin{frame}[#1]{#2}
    \global\beamer@shrinktrue
    \gdef\beamer@shrinkframebox{\setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\beamer@frametextheight{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5\linewidth,y=0.5\beamer@frametextheight]
        \path[use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        \BODY
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{frame}}

%\NewEnviron{tikzframe}[2][c]{%
%\begin{frame}[#1]{#2}%
%   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5\linewidth,y=0.4\paperheight]
%      \path[use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
%      \BODY
%   \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzframe}{Title}
    \node at (-.5,0) {A};
    \node at (.5,0) {B};
%   \only<2>{\node at (.5,0) {B};}
\end{tikzframe}

\end{document}
```

do you have ideas what is wrong?

Comment: For the overlays to work beamer is trying to find literal `\begin,\end{frame}` but can't find it since it is buried in the new environment. I doubt there is a solution but who knows.

Comment: I've updated the code just to show that it may work in principle, but for the commented version of the environment there is no automatic calculation of the textheight...

Comment: It seems like in my original MWE giving a frame `[shrink]` will initialize some macros. In your case you try to apply the third method without the initialization so it fails. I will try to dig out details.

Comment: If you add `\def\beamer@shrinkfactorinv{1}` at the beginning of your document then everything works fine. It is not clear to me what is the meaning of `\beamer@shrinkfactorinv` while there is another macro called `\beamer@shrinkfactor`.

Comment: Normally beamer generates the frame BEFORE the frame title, which means it cannot compute the height available until after the frame is done.

Comment: @Symbol1 I confirm that it works fine after adding this definition. I'd select your 'hack' as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to compute the frame text height.  I used a `\rule` in place of tikzpicture to simplify matters.  Note that it does not leave room for the navigation buttons at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,environ}
\newlength{\mytextheight}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{tikzframe}[2][c]{%
\begin{frame}[#1]{#2}
    \setbox0=\vbox{%
      \vbox{}%
      {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{frametitle}\vskip0.25em}%
    }%
    \setlength{\mytextheight}{\dimexpr\textheight-\ht0-\dp0}%
    \rule{\linewidth}{\mytextheight}
\end{frame}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzframe}{Title}
%    \node at (-.5,0) {A};
%    \node at (.5,0) {B};
%   \only<2>{\node at (.5,0) {B};}
\end{tikzframe}

\end{document}
```

---

here is the computation as performed by beamer:

```
  \ifx\beamer@frametitle\@empty%
    \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\box\voidb@x%
  \else%
    \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\vbox{%
      \vbox{}%
      {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{frametitle}\vskip0.25em}%
    }%
  \fi%
  \ifbeamer@plainframe%
    \beamer@frametextheight=\paperheight%
  \else%
    \beamer@frametextheight=\textheight%
  \fi%
  \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\ht\beamer@frametitlebox%
  \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\dp\beamer@frametitlebox%
  \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\beamer@frametopskip%
```

Comment: Indeed, one can calculate the textheight for a frame in the normal style with the title box. However, the code doesn't account for situations when the title is not present and/or when the plain style is used.

Comment: Do you consider that to be a serious possibility?  Also it doesn't subtract \beamer@frametopskip or \beamer@framebottomskip (which are always 0pt but could conceivably be changed).