# How to know the tikz working area coordinates in a beamer frame with header and footer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, coordinates

In this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz), slightly modified, the positionning of 'N' has been corrected with `textheight` to not be masked by the header:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=north] at ($(current page.north)+(0,-0.1\textheight)$) {N};
  \node[anchor=west] at (current page.west) {W};
  \node[anchor=east] at (current page.east) {E};
  \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south) {S};
  \node at (current page.center) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- Is there other metrics than `textheight` to manage the different areas of the frame (header, footer, between) for tikz drawing?
- Which one in particular permits to work *between* from 0.0 to 1.0?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397523/tikz-based-beamer-frame/397557?r=SearchResults&s=2|44.9584#397557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tikzmark` one can automatically get the position where the frametitle ends:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\tikzmark{endframetitle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at (pic cs:endframetitle) {N};
  \node[anchor=west] at (current page.west) {W};
  \node[anchor=east] at (current page.east) {E};
  \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south) {S};
  \node at (current page.center) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

edit:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\tikzmark{endframetitle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node  at (pic cs:endframetitle) {N};
  \node[anchor=west] at (current page.west) {W};
  \node[anchor=east] at (current page.east) {E};
  \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south) {S};
  \node at (current page.center) {C};
  \fill[red] let \p1 = (pic cs:endframetitle),
                 \p2 = (current page.center) in
                    (\x2,\y1) circle (0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 'N' is actually at the right vertical position with your proposition, but not centered for the horizontal position. Could you improve it please?

Comment: I have added `\fill (0cm,0cm) circle (5pt);` which shows that your solution writes 'N' on the `y` axis as expected. The remaining problem is how to center the origin of the xy coordinate system

Comment: I don't find the *pic* coordinate system in the *pgfmanual.pdf*. Where could I find a description for it please? Sorry, § 14.19

Comment: @lalebarde the pic coordinate syntax comes from the `tikzmark` library. This has an own manual and is not include in the pgfmanual. To find the manual, open a command line and type `texdoc tikzmark`

Comment: @lalebarde To get the coordinate in the center, use the `calc` library. This library allows to mix the x and y coordinates of different coordinated. In This case use the y coordinate from `pic cs:endframetitle` and the x coordinate from `current page.center`

Comment: @lalebarde Please see the edit in my answer for the calculations