# Fill first column in multicols in beamer frame

Tags: beamer, multicol

I would like to use `multicol` in a beamer frame but have the first column fill with text before the second one.

It appears that `\begin{multicols*}...` cannot be used to achieve this effect because beamer typesets the contents in a box without a height set so multicols doesn't know the limiting height.

[Is there a simple command for the available height in a beamer slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278429/is-there-a-simple-command-for-the-available-height-in-a-beamer-slidem) references `\beamer@frametextheight` but this appears to only be set late in the typesetting process.

Is there a way to achieve this effect? I'm okay with solutions that require multiple passes.

Comment: Consider that filling a slide with lots of text, specially in multiple columns, is not conductive to readability.

Comment: Beamer has an environment to use [columns](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Beamer_Presentations%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_2)%E2%80%94Lists%2C_Columns%2C_Pictures%2C_Descriptions_and_Tables). You could simulate it with [minipage](https://latexref.xyz/minipage.html)s. Its second optional argument specifies the height.

Comment: @Celdor it's my understanding that with the columns environment you mentioned, you must explicitly specify which text goes in which column. I need auto-splitting columns.

Comment: why use beamer at all? it is really designed (like most presentation classes) around manual choice of page (and so column) breaks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've started looking at just setting the page margins manually and not using beamer.