# Pause in beamer multicols does not fill the first colmn first

Tags: beamer, multicol, pause

I have a code like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\bm}{\begin{multicols*}{2}}
\newcommand{\em}{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\bm

First sentence. \pause

Second sentence. \pause

Third sentence. \pause

Fourth sentence.

\em
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Although in regular documents `\begin{multicols*}` fills the first column, then fills the second column, it does not work when I insert pauses.

I understand why it doesn't work, because there is nothing else to fill yet. I also know some workarounds such as using `\only<2->` or `\uncover<2->` etc.

However, **the codes are already written** by many people, and I would love to add something to the preamble instead of manually changing every line, or perhaps changing something in the newcommands. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to propely use the multicols package in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152057/how-to-propely-use-the-multicols-package-in-beamer)

Comment: @user1146332 Thanks, it tells me that \begin{multicols*} is meaningless, and it uses \begin{multicols} anyway, because there is no vertical space. Now the question becomes whether there is a way to actually define a maximal height.

Comment: I don't think that you need a way to limit the height because you are the one who puts the content inside the frame. If there is to much content in the `multicol` environment it will always break your layout. Where should the exceeding content be placed? Beamer doesn't know the concept of page breaks.

Comment: @user1146332 It's not a duplicate.

Comment: Anys news on this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not answer yet, but this snippet works fine, is this what you expect ?
I changed the `\em` and `\bm` names because `beamer` complains `\em` is already defined. Also, your `multicols*` is not necessary, as already stated in previous comments.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\bmult}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\newcommand{\emult}{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\bmult

First sentence. \pause

Second sentence. \pause

Third sentence. \pause

Fourth sentence.

\emult
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```